# Unable to view Gatling report on Jenkins

Tags: scala, jenkins, load, jenkins-plugins, gatling

I'm using Gatling Jenkins plugin to track Gatling simulations and generate reports.

It seems to be working fine:

Log
[image: Log]

When a simulation is done and a report is generated, clicking on the report link results in a prompt to download the whole report (including JS files, etc...) as a zip file instead of opening the report in the browser.

Report Link
[image: Report Link]

Save Prompt
[image: Save Prompt]

How could I view the results' index.html file directly from the browser?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In older versions of the Gatling OSS Jenkins plugin, it was possible to display the reports directly in Jenkins.

Jenkins modern versions consider serving files from the Jenkins' filesystem to be extremely unsafe and disabled by default (and you have to enable some scary unrecommended options to turn it on). Indeed, any other job could be tampering those files and injecting malicious content.

So sadly, we had to drop this feature.

Comment: I was wondering why I am not able to see the html report in jenkins. Thank you for the Info..

Comment: Hi, isn't there any solution or workaround to have previous behavior? It is really annoying and also time-consuming to download and open the test results each time.

Comment: Gatling Enterprise/Cloud.